# DynamoDB updated only partially

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want to update my DynamoDB through java using dynamoDBMapper Library.
What I did is to push messages(updates I want to executed) to one SQS, and let my java code to consume these messages and update my dynamoDB. 
I found that when I push more than 150 messages in a short using a script, all the data can be consumed but only parts of the record in DynamoDB was updated.
The code to update DynamoDB like this:

```
@Service
public class PersistenceMessageProcessingServiceImpl implements PersistenceMessageProcessingService{

    @Override
    public void process(TextMessage textMessage){
        String eventData = textMessage.getText();
        updateEventStatus(eventData);
    }

    /* 
    each input is a caseDetail messages in Event Table

    get data, parse data and update relative records partially in dynamodb.
    finally check if still any open cases, if not change state of event
    */
    private void updateEventStatus(String eventData) throws ParseException, IOException {
        RetryUtils retryUtils = new RetryUtils(maxRetries, waitTimeInMilliSeconds, influxService);
        SNowResponse serviceNowResponse = parseData(eventData);
        EventCaseMap eventCaseMap = eventCaseMapRepository.findBySysId(sysId);
        if (eventCaseMap != null) {
            Event event = eventRepository.findByEventId(eventCaseMap.getSecurityEventManagerId());
            CaseManagementDetails caseManagementDetails = event.getCaseManagementDetails();

            Case existingCaseDetails = getCaseByCaseSystemId(caseManagementDetails, sysId);

            caseDetails.setCaseStatus('Resolved');
            caseDetails.setResolution(serviceNowResponse.getCloseCode());
            caseDetails.setResolvedBy("A");
            caseDetails.setAssessment(serviceNowResponse.getAssessment());
            caseDetails.setResolutionSource("SEM");
            retryUtils.run(() -> {
                    return eventRepository.updateEvent(event); }, RETRY_MEASUREMENT);

        }

        boolean stillOpen = false;
        for(Case existingCase : caseManagementDetails.getCases()){
            if(("OPEN").equals(existingCase.getCaseStatus().toString())){
                stillOpen = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!stillOpen){
            event.setState('CLOSED');
        }


    }


    private Case getCaseByCaseSystemId(CaseManagementDetails caseManagementDetails, String sysId) {
        Case caseDetails = null;
        if (caseManagementDetails != null) {
            List<Case> caseList = caseManagementDetails.getCases();
            for (Case c : caseList) {
                if (c.getCaseSystemId() != null && c.getCaseSystemId().equalsIgnoreCase(sysId)) {
                    caseDetails = c;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return caseDetails;
    }


}

/* EventCaseMap Table in my DynamoDB

data model is like this for EventCaseMap Table:
{
  "caseSystemId": "bb9cc488dbf67b40b3d57709af9619f8",
  "securityEventManagerId": "756813a4-4e48-4abb-b37e-da00e931583b"
}
*/
@Repository
public class EventCaseMapRepositoryImpl implements EventCaseMapRepository {

    @Autowired
    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    @Override
    public EventCaseMap findBySysId(String sysId) {
        EventCaseMap eventCaseMap = new EventCaseMap();
        eventCaseMap.setCaseSystemId(sysId);
        return dynamoDBMapper.load(eventCaseMap, DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT.config());
    }

}


/*
data model is like this for Event Table:

{
  "caseManagementDetails": {
    "cases": [
      {
        "caseId": "SIR0123456",
        "caseStatus": "OPEN",
      },
      {
        "caseId": "SIR0654321",
        "caseStatus": "OPEN",
      },
      {
        many other cases(about two hundreds).....
      }
    ]

    },
    "state": "OPEN",
    "securityEventManagerId": "756813a4-4e48-4abb-b37e-da00e931583b"
}

*/


@Repository
public class EventRepositoryImpl implements EventRepository {

    @Autowired
    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;

    @Override
    public Event findByEventId(String eventId) {
        Event event = new Event();
        event.setSecurityEventManagerId(eventId);
        return dynamoDBMapper.load(event, DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.CONSISTENT.config());
    }

        @Override
    public boolean updateEvent(Event event) {
        dynamoDBMapper.save(event, DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES.config());
        return false;
    }

}
```

I already try to push the message and consume the message one by one in both 'RUN' and 'DEBUG' model in my Intellij. evertything works fine, all the cases can be updated.
So I was wondering if any inconsistency problems in DynamoDB, but I have already using Strong Consistency in my code.

So do any body know what happened in my code?

There is the input, output, expected output:

**input:**
many json files like this:

```
{
  "number": "SIR0123456",
  "state": "Resolved",
  "sys_id": "bb9cc488dbf67b40b3d57709af9619f8",
  "MessageAttributes": {
    "TransactionGuid": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Value": "093ddb36-626b-4ecc-8943-62e30ffa2e26"
    }
  }
}
{
  "number": "SIR0654321",
  "state": "Resolved",
  "sys_id": "bb9cc488dbf67b40b3d57709af9619f7",
  "MessageAttributes": {
    "TransactionGuid": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Value": "093ddb36-626b-4ecc-8943-62e30ffa2e26"
    }
  }
}
```

**output for Event Table:**

```
{
  "caseManagementDetails": {
    "cases": [
      {
        "caseId": "SIR0123456",
        "caseStatus": "RESOLVED",
      },
      {
        "caseId": "SIR0654321",
        "caseStatus": "OPEN"
      },
      {
        many other cases(about two hundreds).....
      }
    ]

    },
    "state": "OPEN",
    "securityEventManagerId": "756813a4-4e48-4abb-b37e-da00e931583b"
}
```

**Expected output for Event Table:**

```
{
  "caseManagementDetails": {
    "cases": [
      {
        "caseId": "SIR0123456",
        "caseStatus": "RESOLVED",
      },
      {
        "caseId": "SIR0654321",
        "caseStatus": "RESOLVED"
      },
      {
        many other cases(about two hundreds).....
      }
    ]

    },
    "state": "OPEN",
    "securityEventManagerId": "756813a4-4e48-4abb-b37e-da00e931583b"
}
```

Comment: EventId seems to be the key. Other are secondary indexes?

Comment: @YatiSawhney in Event Table, securityEventManagerId(is this what you mean EventId?) is the key. There are two second indexes one is 'state'(as shown), another is 'findingUniqueID'(didn't use it) in this snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in that when DynamoDB persistent data, it run in a multi-threading way. so if we consume all these data in a short time, there may some threads didn't finish. So the result we saw was just the result of the last thread not that of all threads.